# Why * is Inserted in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

This happened when I was just testing.
I've created a table as

```
    Create Table Test_Table
(
    Field_char char(1)
);
```

When I want to insert value with code

```
Insert Into Test_Table(Field_char)
Select 13;
```

It inserts '*' in the column. For single digits it inserts them as it is. If the length is modified from 1 to 2, similar thing happen for 3 digits input such as 100 etc.

Why is this?

Comment: Because `SELECT CONVERT(char(1),13)`  --> `*`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your create statement you set the length of Field_char to 1 (char(1)). This means that your entries must have a length smaller or equal to 1. valid entries are 1,2 etc. Invalid entries are 12, 13 as they are longer than 1 char -> * is a placeholder to indicate invalid values.

**EDIT: (Thanks To Vladimir)**

To be more precise take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

> **Truncating and Rounding Results**
>
> [...] Conversions to char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, binary, and varbinary are truncated, except for the conversions shown in the following table.

There we have the following entry:

> From data type **int** to data type **char** result *

where * = Result length too short to display

Comment: The only answer that actually explains where this * comes from. Add a link to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx and quote from it: Truncating and Rounding Results
Conversions to char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, binary, and varbinary are truncated, except for the conversions shown in the following table. * = Result length too short to display

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing

```
Insert Into Test_Table(Field_char)
Select 13;
```

The it is converting int to char. So your 13 is converted into *. If you want you can check by writing

```
select CONVERT(char(1),13)
```

If you want to see the result as 13 then you need to put that in single inverted comma like this:

```
Insert Into Test_Table(Field_char)
Select '13';
```

And also you need to increase the size of column as char(1) can hold only one character.

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/af155/1)**

Answer (score 0):

[image]
It simply Convert Int to Char

for Example

```
select CONVERT(char(1),13)
```

it will give *

Sql Implicitly convert int to char which is you column type..